# How do I submit user-input data and reflect it in a vertical table?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am a beginner and I am trying to write a simple program that calculates a late fee based on a given previous invoice amount/payments. I am stumped in the early portion of this project and basically where I am trying to start is by taking the user inputted values and having them show in my table below, for some reason I cannot figure this out. You can check out what I have so far here: http://176.32.230.9/testingnicoledelarosa.com/

This is the code I have thus far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Late Fee Calculator</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script>

    function addRow() {

        var table= document.getElementByID("results");
        var row= document.createElement("tr");
        var td1= document.createElement("td");
        var td2= document.createElement("td");
        var td3= document.createElement("td");
        td1.innerHTML = document.getElementByID("invoiceAmount").value;
        td2.innerHTML = document.getElementByID("previousBalance").value;
        td3.innerHTML = document.getElementByID("paymentAdjustments").value;
        row.appendChild(td1);
        row.appendChild(td2);
        row.appendChild(td3);
        table.children[0].appendChild(row);

    }


</script>

</head>

<body>

<div>

    <form>

        Invoice Amount:<br>

        <input type="number" id="invoiceAmount">

        <br>
        <br>

        Previous Balance:<br>

        <input type="number" id="previousBalance">

        <br>
        <br>

        Payments/Adjustments:<br>

        <input type="number" id="paymentAdjustments">

        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addRow()">

    </form>



</div>    

    <br>

<div>

    <table border="1" id="results">

    <tr>

        <th>Total Invoice Amount</th>
        <td>data</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <th>Previous Balance</th>
        <td>data</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <th>Payments/Adjustments</th>
        <td>data</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <th>Late Fee</th>
        <td>data</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <th>Balance (Amount Due)</th>
        <td>data</td>

    </tr>

    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two reasons.

First, the "document.getElementByID" calls should be "document.getElementById" (lower-case d).

But, to prevent your form from actually submitting and reloading the page (and in your case clearing out the data in the table), you could add a 'return false;' at the end of your addRow() function. So it would look like this:

```
function addRow() {
    var table= document.getElementById("results");
    var row= document.createElement("tr");
    var td1= document.createElement("td");
    var td2= document.createElement("td");
    var td3= document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("invoiceAmount").value;
    td2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("previousBalance").value;
    td3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("paymentAdjustments").value;
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    table.children[0].appendChild(row);
    return false;
}
```

And your input tag would then look like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return addRow();">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helps me move along. Sorry for such a beginner question!

Comment: No problem at all, we all started there :) If this answer worked for you, could you please mark it as accepted?